# ESRI geometry compression algorithm in JAVA

Tags: java, algorithm, compression, esri

I am writing ESRI geometry compression algorithm in JAVA, I am using this [link](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/ArcObjects/esrinetworkanalyst/INACompactStreetDirection_CompressedGeometry.htm).

Using instructions mentioned in provided link, this is my current code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String dirPoints = "-118.356654545455,34.1146;-118.356436363636,34.1143272727273;-118.356418181818,34.1142363636364;-118.356490909091,34.1137636363636";
    String compressedGeometry = "";
    double xPointPrev = 0.0;
    double yPointPrev = 0.0;
    int coefficient = 55000;
    String coefficient_32 = Integer.toString(coefficient, 32);
    compressedGeometry = coefficient_32 + compressedGeometry;

    String[] path_XY = dirPoints.split(";");
    for (int i = 0, leni = path_XY.length; i < leni; i++) {

        String[] xy = path_XY[i].split(",");
        double pointX = Double.parseDouble(xy[0].trim());
        double pointY = Double.parseDouble(xy[1].trim());

        int xDifference = (int) Math.round(coefficient * (pointX - xPointPrev));
        int yDifference = (int) Math.round(coefficient * (pointY - yPointPrev));

        String xDifference_32 = Integer.toString(xDifference, 32);
        compressedGeometry += xDifference_32;

        String yDifference_32 = Integer.toString(yDifference, 32);
        compressedGeometry += yDifference_32;

        xPointPrev = pointX;
        yPointPrev = pointY;
    }
    System.out.println(compressedGeometry);
}
```

Expected output: "+1lmo-66l1f+1p8af+c-f+1-5-4-q"

But I am getting this: "1lmo-66l1g1p8afc-f1-5-4-q"

What am I missing? Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Integer.toString()

```
"If the first argument is not negative, no sign character appears in the result."
```

Therefore I think you need to add the "+".

(And I think the f-g there is their typo).